# Is it Ok to delete duplicate answers posted on several questions by the same user?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-answers, duplicate-answers

If the user voted to close the question as a duplicate each times before copying it's answer; and the answer *(which isn't an exact copy in each cases)* fit on all the related questions.

Should those kind of answers be all deleted together *(including his answer on the original question which wasn't close as duplicate)*?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the scenario. A user posts an answer on a question and then votes to close the question as duplicate. He does that several times. Each time his answer is similar, but not identical. Is that what you're describing? Is there anything wrong with the answer itself, besides that it's similar to another answer by the same user?

Comment: If the answers are exact duplicates I **think** a mod flag is automatically raised. Although maybe that's only if they are in quick succession (or it could be false entirely).

Comment: @OGHaza : but many user modify there question in some way (for example: two broad questions asking for the general steps to cross-compile : the first 1 ask : `What are the general steps to convert C++ to Sparc64` the second `What are the steps to convert C to MIPS IV?`) : Then the use may copy it's answer, describing what cross-compiling is (and what are the steps), with just replacing `C`with `C++`and `Sparc64` with `MIPS`.

Comment: @deceze : Since you can see deleted posts, just look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24601290/2284570) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24631673/2284570).

Comment: For those who don't understand what I'm asking : **Is it Ok to delete not-exact duplicate answers of duplicate question when the answerer flagged the questions?** You might also want to read the [comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266795/2284570) and suggest an edit.

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like the user is just trying to farm reputation. The reason we close as duplicate is so that all of the answers to a question are in one place. There's no reason to copy/paste an answer to duplicate questions, even if there is an edit. If the questions are duplicates, one answer on one question should be enough.

---

Note: Hypothetically, if the user is spamming 12 questions in an hour with the same answer that links to a product, project, or web site, all of their answers are subject to deletion. Hypothetically.

Comment: So what action should be taken, if any? Should one of the answers be flagged? If they are continually voting to close *then* (if this is the case) answering, it doesn't seem like good conduct.

Comment: @BilltheLizard : I added a concern to my question.

Comment: @codeMagic Yes, it's ok to flag this. Please use the "Other" flag option and leave a note that the user is copy/pasting duplicate answers to multiple questions.

Comment: @user2284570 The original answer can stay. There just don't need to be multiple copies everywhere.

Comment: The duplicate answer thing I know is bad. But should it be pointed out that they are answering **and** voting to close or is that a non-issue? I know my thoughts on it but would like clarification from someone with the powah

Comment: @codeMagic Yes, that is worth mentioning in the flag note.

Comment: @codeMagic : Ok, but sometimes the answer on the original question [get deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24629510/2284570).

Comment: My initial reaction was that the user was trying to help questioners who don't follow links to duplicate questions.  I fear you are right though, and it is reputation farming :-(