# Copied answer closed on similar questions, despite answer being correct

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, duplicate-answers

So the other day I was looking into a good way of injecting some asp mvc action into an id'd container. I've done some browsing through google with site:stackoverflow.com. There were multiple similar questions regarding the topic. Since I wasn't comfortable with any of the given solutions I created my own.

I then posted it as answer to the top 3 questions on Google, so everyone who stumbles across the same question, in order to find a good solution, will find it too. If you look at it you can see that I put in some effort to craft a type safe solution readily usable as extension method, so I only wanted to do a good deed by sharing it.

However my answer was then deleted despite being correct and being different from other answers in that question.

I don't see what's wrong with copy pasting my own answer into other questions if it helps the person, since each question should be answered standalone rather than just crossreferencing?

One of the questions would be here:

[How do you refresh the contents of a div in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260713/how-do-you-refresh-the-contents-of-a-div-in-jquery/27302871#27302871)

I'd be interested in moderator replies on this in particular. Just wondering if everyone would have decided like that.

I looked into this: [Copy-pasting the contents of another answer to the same question — with attribution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269396/copy-pasting-the-contents-another-answer-to-the-same-question-with-attribution) (which is a different case)

and this: 
[Can we auto-flag answers that are clearly copy-pasted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270311/can-we-auto-flag-answers-that-are-clearly-copy-pasted)

where ChrisF wrote:

> As a regular user, as long as the answer is correct, then all you can do is leave a comment for the poster telling them that they should be flagging duplicate questions rather than answering. If the answer is incorrect then obviously a down-vote is welcome.

which I agree with, if it's a fresh question. But if it's an older one it'll display variations of methods to approach a solution, which would be sad to lose. Personally I had about 5-10 "oh nice. that is a way better solution"-moments just from browsing through some answers.

Comment: From ChrisF's answer that you mention: _"Duplicate answers are already automatically flagged by the system."_ If you copy-pasted the answer across multiple questions, it raised an auto-flag. A mod saw it, and, _as a moderator and not a regular user_ deleted the duplicate answers as it is inappropriate to duplicate answers in such a fashion.

Comment: @Kendra i know it's inappropriate to duplicate questions. I haven't seen anything about that regarding answers. not to mention that in order to actually duplicate an answer the answer would have to be present in the same question, which is not the case.

Comment: Andreas, [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266795/2607247) will also shed some light for you. [This one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271677/2607247) will also be a good read for you. Basically, yes, if you copy-paste your answers, mods will delete them.

Comment: If the question can be answered by copy/pasting another of your answers, then the question is clearly a duplicate and should be flagged as such. The link to the original question will provide them with the answer. It is highly unlikely that you will find a question that is not a duplicate where a copy/paste of another answer is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I'm not sure *why* your answer is correct.  I confess that I don't understand much of ASP, but all you've got is a block of code and some sample usages.

All that really tells me is that I could get away with Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V, not that this is a viable solution to any problem I have.

Second, what you've essentially done is duplicate information.  There's no reason to do that; if you want to reference an answer (but the question isn't a duplicate), then put it in a comment.  The question you reference is both not a duplicate (it's talking more about the JavaScript side than the ASP side), and is more clear with a pure JS answer.

Comment: it was tagged as asp mvc however, which in all cases was used. now while the question didnt explicitly ask for a mvc extension method it still does the work for you in a fashion which is refactor friendly. I doubt you would suggest not giving a better solution, a person might not have known about because he didnt explicitly ask for something.